# C++ using C# DLL. Problem with InvokeHelper

Tags: c#, c++, dll, visual-c++-6

I have a c# dll, really simple:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ClassTestPourCPP
{
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.ClassInterface(System.Runtime.InteropServices.ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
    public class MainClass
    {
        public int GiveInt2()
        {
            return 2;
        }
    }
}
```

And I want my C++ app (VC6) to use it. So I built my dll with the option "set visible to com" enabled.
I regasm the DLL, so I have the tlb file.
Then I imported the tlb in the IDE, It generated a .h & .cpp file, exactly like it should.

```
long _MainClass::GiveInt2()
{
    long result;
    InvokeHelper(0x60020004, DISPATCH_METHOD, VT_I4, (void*)&result, NULL);
    return result;
}
```

The problem is now when I call the method, it just .. does not thing, giving me a wrong output (it gives the value of result before the call, like if there is a try catch inside the InvokeHelper)

Why isn't it working? :(

Thank you very much!

Comment: Unguessable from the provided info.  At least use the #import directive.

Answer (score 1):

Did you call `CoInitialize` before trying to use the COM object?

Comment: No I didn't actually. I just tried but it doesn't affect the behavior of my c# method call: 
the code is basic:

CoInitialize(NULL);
_MainClass m_class;
long a = m_class.GiveInt2();

Comment: @user621766: You might want to start by instantiating a native COM object (a number come pre-installed with Windows), and only introduce the complexity of .NET after you know COM is initialized right and working.

Comment: Hey, Yeah I have to admit it seems more complicated than I thought. Could you give me some native COM object names you talked about Ben? Thx!

Comment: For example, Windows comes with [a `Dictionary` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4.aspx) intended for use in scripts.  The ProgID is `Scripting.Dictionary`.